# Ajax dentro de ciclo for

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Tengo una función que lee valores (nombres de host) de un txtarea lina a linea, luego mediante un for y un ajax consulto un dato adicional y lo paso a otro txtarea.
El problema es que yo necesito que lo actualice linea a linea pero siempre lo hace al final, es decir todos los datos juntos, me gustaría que a medida que la consulta ajax termina de cada host escriba el resultado en la txtarea de salida. 
Esta es mi función:

```
function searchenv() {
    hostenv = '';
    var lines = document.getElementById("txtinput").value.split("\n");
    for(var i = 0;i < lines.length;i++){
        host=lines[i];
        $.ajax({
            url: '../data/searchenv.php',
            data: {hostname : host},
            dataType: 'json',
            async: false,
            success:function(data){
                if (data.length) {
                    hostenv = hostenv+host+" - "+data[0].MULTIENVIRONMENT+"\n";
                } else {
                    hostenv = hostenv+host+" - SIN DATOS"+"\n";
                }
            }
        });
        document.getElementById("txtoutput").value=hostenv;
    }
}
```

¿Alguien puede ayudarme? Gracias!

Comment: Tienes algun error?

Comment: No, funciona perfectamente, pero no escribe linea a lina en el ttxtarea de salida, es decir si son 50 lineas en el txtarea de entrada escribe las 50 lineas juntas todas a la vez, lo que necesito es que actualice linea a linea esto: document.getElementById("txtoutput").value=hostenv

Comment: me parese una forma demaciado rudimentaria de tratar un problema aparte del costo ya que consume demaciados recursos en solicitudes
te recomiendo replantear tu logica.
no obstante podrias hacerlo con `fetch/then, async/await or promise` que esperan a que termine la ejecucion de una linea de codigo para continuar con la siguiente y viendolo asi a lo rapido rapido estas escribiendo cada resultado en el mismo id `txtoutput`

Comment: Gracias, no veo como mejorar la consulta, es decir los host están en cada linea, los leo linea a linea y consulto sus datos, por favor si tienes un momento me puedes dar mas detalles de como dices mejorar? Gracias.

Comment: Sube esta linea document.getElementById("txtoutput").value=hostenv; al success: function.

Comment: Ya lo intente antes y nada.

Comment: ajax es asíncronico, el for continua aunque el ajax no haya contestado. Lo que debes hacer es actualizar el control desde la funcion success. que se dispara cada vez que responde

Answer (score 0):

```
function searchenv() {
    hostenv = '';
    var lines = document.getElementById("txtinput").value.split("\n");
    for(var i = 0;i < lines.length;i++){
        host=lines[i];
        $.when($.ajax({
            url: '../data/searchenv.php',
            data: {hostname : host},
            dataType: 'json',
            //async: false,
            success:function(data){
                document.getElementById("txtoutput").value=hostenv
                if (data.length) {
                    hostenv = hostenv+host+" - "+data[0].MAPFRE_MULTIENVIRONMENT+"\n";
                } else {
                    hostenv = hostenv+host+" - SIN DATOS"+"\n";
                }
            }
        })).done(function(data) {
            document.getElementById("txtoutput").value=hostenv;
        }); 
    }
}
```